# How to set up VS Code editor for BEM features in Emmet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

https://pawelgrzybek.com/bem-with-emmet/

How I can apply this preferences?
If I'll paste it (look at picture) – nothing changes, doesn't work.

```
{
   "bem.elementSeparator": "__",
   "bem.modifierSeparator": "--",
   "bem.shortElementPrefix": "_",
   "lorem.defaultLang": "ru",
}
```

[image: My User Settings in VS Code]

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be specified in settings file (`ctrl+,` to open user settings) in this way:

[image]

Comment: Did you include this as well:
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "html": {
            "filters": "bem"
        }
    },

Comment: Yes, I did. You can see it on image in my previously comment.